# Using one md-datepicker to select a range

Tags: angular-material2

Can you select multiple days in a single Angular Material2 `md-datepicker`?

I want to select a period, e.g. from today until 28 of the month, all without using 2 datepickers, one for the beginning and one for the end of the period.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the md-datepicker in Angular Material2 does not support ranges, though the team [has indicated](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/2.0.0-beta.12/src/lib/datepicker/datepicker.md#current-state) that they plan on adding support for this feature in the future. There is also an [open issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4763) requesting this feature.